encoding and decoding strings in dm-script and Python
My files sometimes contain multibyte characters in file-path or text in the file.
And I can not read the correct strings from the file.
I know the best way is to avoid using multibyte characters...
Unfortunately system encoding of my PC is Shift-JIS, not UTF.
This is the default setting of Windows system in my country.
And the default encoding of Python is UTF-8.
This is examples of reading multibyte-charactres from dm-script and python.
"shift-jis.txt" and "utf-8.txt" have the same strings but different encoding.
TagGroup txtTg(string filepath,number encoding)
{
    string text
    TagGroup TextInFileTg=NewTagList()
    number fileID=OpenFileForReading(filepath)
    while(ReadFileLine(fileID,encoding,text))
    {
        TextInFileTg.TagGroupInsertTagAsString(infinity(),text)
    }
    CloseFile(fileID)
    return TextInFileTg
}

string dirpath="C:\\Users\\arksa\\Documents\\scripts"

TagGroup flistTg=GetFilesInDirectory(dirpath,1)
string ext="txt"
string fname,fpath,text
number fileID
TagGroup fTg=NewTagGroup()
number encoding
for(number i=0;i<flistTg.TagGroupCountTags();i++)
{
    flistTg.TagGroupGetTagAsString("["+i+"]:Name",fname)
    fpath=PathConcatenate(dirpath,fname)
    if(fname.PathExtractExtension(0)==ext)
    {
        if(fname=="shift-jis.txt")
        {
            encoding=0
            fTg.TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup("DM can read "+fname,txtTg(fpath,encoding))
        }
        if(fname=="utf-8.txt")
        {
            for(number j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                encoding=j
                fTg.TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup("DM cannot read "+fname+":"+"encoding="+encoding,txtTg(fpath,encoding))
            }
        }
    }
}

fTg.TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow("text",0)



import DigitalMicrograph as DM
import os

dirpath=r'C:\Users\arksa\Documents\scripts'
files=['shift-jis.txt','utf-8.txt']
encodings=['shift-jis','utf-8']

tag=DM.NewTagGroup()
for i in range(len(files)):
    path=os.path.join(dirpath,files[i])
    ftag=DM.NewTagList()
    with open(path,encoding=encodings[i]) as f:
        for fline in f:
            ftag.InsertTagAsString(-1,str(fline).encode('shift-jis').decode('utf-8','backslashreplace'))
            #print(fline)
    tag.SetTagAsTagGroup("writing strings in "+files[i]+" to tag group from python fails.",ftag)

tag.OpenBrowserWindow(True)



DM-script can read a shift-jis text file correctly, but not for an utf-8 file.
Python can read both shift-jis and utf-8 files, but writing strings to TagGroup fails.
If encoding of multibyte characters is the identical to Windows encoding, only dm-script can deal with strings correctly.
I cannot find the function to write string to TagGroup with arbitrary encoding.

Can you provide the two test-files as download link, so that others can have a look?
To my knowledge, there exists no encoding specific command to write strings to tags in DigitalMicrograph, and I wouldn't be surprised if there would be some fundamental support things missing. To my knowledge, DigitalMicrograph is only specified for English OS in its official description.

Also, can you point out what your actual goal is?

This is the text files. They contain Japanese character. I'm not sure if they are displayed correctly on your PC.
test-files
I'm sorry that my question is not clear. My instrument saves measurement data as binary and metadata as text file. Text file is encoded with UTF-8.
Most of strings in the file are English, but sometimes I encounter multibyte character.
I'd like to read all metadata and store into TagGroup.
I don't care if code is written in dm-script or Python or hybrid scripting.

So, in essence, you have DM read shift-jis files correctly (Can the be output by 'Result()' as well?) because your system OS is set to shift-jis, but the files you want to read are utf-8 (Which DM script does not support.)    Can you not (temporarily) write the utf-8 files as shift-jis file (using Python) then?
It might be a bit clumsy, but if it gets the job done...

Not an answer, but I found something potential useful:
List of "encoding" parameter values as used in script commands in GMS 3.x:
// ENCODE parameter values

SYSTEM_MULTIBYTE = 0x00000000
GATAN            = 0x00000001
UNICODE          = 0x00000002
ROMAN        = 0x01000000
JAPANESE     = 0x01000001
CHINESE_TRAD = 0x01000002
KOREAN       = 0x01000003
ARABIC       = 0x01000004
HEBREW       = 0x01000005
GREEK        = 0x01000006
CYRILLIC     = 0x01000007
DEVANAGARI   = 0x01000009
GURMUKHI     = 0x0100000A
GUJARATI     = 0x0100000B
THAI         = 0x01000015
CHINESE_SIMP = 0x01000019
EASTEUROPE   = 0x0100001D
TURKISH      = 0x01000023       
BALTIC       = 0x01000100      


